# constant polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Can you give me a counter example of this ;

Let $ P: = P (x, y) $ is a polynomial function  with positive coefficients : $$P (x, y)=\sum\limits_{i+j\leq n}^{n} a_{ij}x^{i}y^{j}), \quad  a_{ij}\geq 0 ,\forall i,j$$ $ a, b \ge 0 $ (edit $a\neq b$) such that  $ Q_1 (x) := P (x, b) $ is  constant function  and $ Q_2 (y) := P (a, y) $ is  also constant function , then $ P $ is constant function .

Comment: Let $P(x,y)=xy$, $a=b=0$.

Comment: an oversight  $a\neq b$

Comment: @cerise $P(x,y)=(x-1)y$, $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Comment: but $P(x,y)=(x-1)y=xy-y$ have not positive coefficients

Comment: @cerise My apologies, I missed the "positive coefficients" assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No counterexample exists. Express the polynomial as

$$P(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,j}x^iy^j$$

for $c_{i,j}\geq 0$. Suppose there exist $a,b\geq0$ with $a\neq b$ such that $P(x,b)$ and $P(a,y)$ are both constant polynomials. Since $a\neq b$, $a$ and $b$ cannot both be zero. Without loss of generality, suppose $a\neq 0$. Then we see

$$P(a,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m\left(\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,j}a^i\right)y^j=\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,0}a^i+\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,j}a^i\right)y^j.$$

Since $P(a,y)$ is constant, the coefficients $\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,j}a^i$ on $y^j$ must all be $0$ for $j>0$. But $\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,j}a^i$ is a sum of nonnegative numbers which can therefore only be zero if each term is zero. Hence, $c_{i,j}a^i=0$ for $j>0$ which implies $c_{i,j}=0$ since $a^i\neq 0$. Then we now know

$$P(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^nc_{i,0}x^i.$$

So, it is now clear that $P(x,y)=P(x,b)$. But $P(x,b)$ is a constant polynomial, so $P(x,y)$ is a constant polynomial as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank's